# How to give access to my user and _www

Tags: macos, permission

I am new to mac and running a website through apache server.
The code for my application is being accessed by the _www user, so I set the ownership to _www user but then when I try to edit a file from netbeans I have to give the ownership back to my user.
I dont want to use the my application or netbeans from the root user but is there a way I can give permission to both myuser and _www user to a directory?

Thanks!

Comment: If you open Finder help and search for "set permissions" you should see this article. https://help.apple.com/machelp/mac/10.11/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/mchlp1203 Could you edit this to explain what specifically you are unclear about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a user or a group full access to a folder use

```
chmod +a "user_name allow list,add_file,search,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /path/to/folder
```

You may replace *user_name* by a *group_name*.

To remove the ACL simply replace the +a by -a.

It's similar for a single file - the attributes are different though:

```
chmod +a "user_name allow read,write,execute,delete,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown" /path/to/file
```

Insert a -R for all files in a folder:

```
chmod -R +a "user_name allow read,...
```

Comment: But I think it won't work if the owner is root. Will it?

Comment: @RahulSharma Then you may have to prepend `sudo`